# Dropwizard serve external images directory

Tags: assets, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard API app and I want one endpoint where I can run the call and also upload and image, these images have to be saved in a directory and then served through the same application context.

Is it possible with dropwizard? I can only find static assets bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is similar question already: [Can DropWizard serve assets from outside the jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223724/can-dropwizard-serve-assets-from-outside-the-jar-file)

The above module is mentioned in the [third party](http://modules.dropwizard.io/thirdparty/) modules list of `dropwizard`. There is also [official modules](http://modules.dropwizard.io/official/) list. These two lists are hard to find maybe because the main documentation doesn't reference them.

There is also [dropwizard-file-assets](https://github.com/dirkraft/dropwizard-file-assets) which seems new. I don't know which module will work best for your case. Both are based on `dropwizard`'s [AssetServlet](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-servlets/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/servlets/assets/AssetServlet.java)

If you don't like them you could use it as example how to implement your own. I suspect that the `resource caching` part may not be appropriate for your use case if someone replace the same resource name with new content: https://github.com/dirkraft/dropwizard-file-assets/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/dirkraft/dropwizard/fileassets/FileAssetServlet.java#L129-L141

**Edit:** This is [simple project](https://gitlab.com/zloster/dropwizard-static) that I've made using [dropwizard-configurable-assets-bundle](https://github.com/dropwizard-bundles/dropwizard-configurable-assets-bundle). Follow the instructions in the `README.md`. I think it is doing exactly what you want: put some files in a directory somewhere on the file system (outside the project source code) and serve them if they exist.

Comment: Thank you, I have already seen these posts, but they are about serving static assets, not dynamic files. I tried it quickly with no luck. I will try the others too but I do not think they will do what I want. I will probably end up serving the images from a classic apache...

Comment: @Panos I've made simple project. IMO it is doing what you are trying to achieve. Take a look.